# How to perform multilevel regression on Y?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, pca, multilevel-analysis

We know multiple linear regression has the equation

$$
Y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{11} + ... + \beta_k x_{1k} + \epsilon_1 \\
Y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{21} + ... + \beta_k x_{2k} + \epsilon_2 \\ 
\dots \\
Y_n = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{n1} + ... + \beta_k x_{nk} + \epsilon_n  
$$

Where we try to find the $(\beta_0, \beta_1, \dots \beta_k)$ through some standard python package such as scikit-learn.
Suppose both X and Y are high dimensional data and I need to see whether they are linear regressed on prinicipal component space. So if I take two PC on each of the dependent and independent variable then my equation will be something like this.

$$
Y_1^{pc_1} , Y_1^{pc_2}  = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{11}^{pc_1} + \beta_2x_{11}^{pc_2}... + \beta_{k-1} x_{1k}^{pc_1} + \beta_k x_{1k}^{pc_2} +\epsilon_1 \\
Y_2^{pc_1} , Y_2^{pc_2}  = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{21}^{pc_1} + \beta_2x_{21}^{pc_2}... + \beta_{k-1} x_{2k}^{pc_1} + \beta_k x_{2k}^{pc_2} +\epsilon_2 \\
\dots \\
Y_n^{pc_1} , Y_n^{pc_2}  = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{n1}^{pc_1} + \beta_2x_{n1}^{pc_2}... + \beta_{k-1} x_{nk}^{pc_1} + \beta_k x_{nk}^{pc_2} +\epsilon_1
$$

So in this case how should I use multiple regression concept to lead in principal component regression space and can anyone point me how this can be done in any Python or R package. Thanks.

Comment: The meaning of "use multiple regression concept to lead in principal component regression space" is unclear.  Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It means how to fit Y^(PC1) and Y^(PC2) simultaneously with given x

Comment: I see.  In that case you likely haven't written the equation you mean, because your expressions literally state that the error terms $\epsilon_j$ apply to *both* of the PCs for the $j^\text{th}$ observation, which I doubt you intended.  Once you allow for separate, independent, and identically distributed error terms (do I guess correctly?), this is identical to your initial formulation but with $2n$ observations instead of $n$ of them, so there's nothing to analyze and no special package would be needed.